# What is the proper response to a question being closed as off-topic? How does it get re-opened?

Tags: support, flags, closed-questions

I made a question that was marked as off-topic by ask about manual references. And, I suppose, for the same reason down-voted.

[image]

I've already rewritten its title and body, changing the focus.
So I would like to know how to proceed to it have it unflagged and reopened.

I thought to start a chat with the moderators, however I couldn't see how to do it.

Beside the question fix, what should be my attitude about it?

Answer (score 10):

If you've edited it, it will go into the Re-Open queue automatically, where it will be reviewed. If three community members with sufficient reputation to work in this queue find the edits adequate to make the question suitable for the site, it will be re-opened. If three do not, it will remain closed.

Re-opening questions is not the Moderators' job, it's the community's. So flagging for a moderator would not help.

Sometimes, bringing an issue to Meta can help. A link to the question would be required so that people can find it easily. But generally it's better to wait for the review process...

Answer (score 9):

[Cindy Meister covered the general stuff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392289).

As for your [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384704/how-to-find-out-keystroke-bash-associated-textual-representation), the [reopen review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/24884501) was completed on the post about 9 hours ago. All three reviewers voted to leave the question closed.

I find myself agreeing with the reviewers. This does not appear to be a programming question, and it is not about a tool specifically used by programmers. You will have more luck asking general computer usage questions on [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Since you've specifically tagged this one [ubuntu-18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-18.04), it might also be worth investigating [Ask Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com).